# BigQuery SQL : Dynamically Concat all rows in column by key

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this:

```
Customer    Plan/Date
A           free (20/01/2020-01/02/2020)
A           starter (01/02/2020-01/03/2020)
A           full (01/03/2020)
B           trial (02/03/2020-05/04/2020)
B           full (05/04/2020)
.....
.....
```

I need concat strings in column Plan/Date by Customer Key
And Get Output like this:

```
Customer    Plans
A          free (20/01/2020-01/02/2020), starter (01/02/2020-01/03/2020), full (01/03/2020)
B          trial (02/03/2020-05/04/2020), full (05/04/2020)
```

The main challenge is that the number of rows for each customer can be different

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a string, then you want `string_agg()`:

```
select customer,
       string_agg(plans, ', ')
from t
group by customer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below - I think it is important to keep proper order in final list

```
select Customer,
  string_agg(Plan_Date, ', ' order by parse_date('%d/%m/%Y', regexp_extract(Plan_Date, r'\((.{10})'))) as Plans
from `project.dataset.table`
group by Customer
```